# How do I tell the action on a form not to execute when cancel button clicked?

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I have page "A" with a form:

```
<form id="formA" method='post' action="somePage.php" name="formA">
    ... some input here ...
    <div id="save-button"><input type="submit" value="Save" onclick=""/></div>
    <div id="cancel-button"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="self.close()"/></div>
</form>
```

When I click "Save" it should and does execute "somePage.php" which among other things writes to a file.
When I click "Cancel" I want page "A" to close (which it does) but it still executes "somePage.php".
How can I keep that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="cancel-button"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="self.close()"/></div>
```

to

```
<div id="cancel-button"><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="self.close()"/></div>
```

type cannot be **submit**

Answer (score -3):

```
<form id = 'formA' method = 'post' action = 'nextPage.php'>
 ...textboxes etc...
<div id="save-button"><input type="submit" value="Save" onclick=""/></div>
</form>
<form id = 'formB' method = 'post' action = 'prevPage.php'>
<div id="cancel-button"><input type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick=""/></div>
</form>
```

try it

Comment: why, would you do it like that?

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.